# 403 when Azure Machine Learning workspace reads a blob that it just created

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

When I create a custom environment from within a notebook in my Azure Machine Learning workspace, I can successfully `Environment.add_private_pip_wheel` such that the .whl file I reference ends up in my connected Azure Storage location.

However, when I then build the environment and use that resulting storage path as a pip dependency, during the image build I am hit with a:

```
403 ERROR: Could not install requirement mywheel==1.23.4.5 from blob_url?sv=xxx&sr=b&sig=yyy&st=zzz&se=aaa&sp=r (from -r /azureml-environment-setup/condaenv.ewii6__u.requirements.txt (line 2)) because of HTTP error 403 Client Error: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. for url: blob_url?sv=xxx&sr=b&sig=yyy&st=zzz&se=aaa&sp=r for URL blob_url?sv=xxx&sr=b&sig=yyy&st=zzz&se=aaa&sp=r
```

Does the build process take place on a different resource that I need to add to the storage account ACL perhaps? What else could explain notebook cell A being able to write to storage but notebook cell B not being allowed to then read it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-online-endpoints.md) to troubleshoot online endpoints.

If the endpoint was created with a User Assigned Identity, the user's managed identity must have Storage blob data reader permission on the storage account for the workspace, and AcrPull permission on the Azure Container Registry (ACR) for the workspace.